# Regular expression to find active console.log

Tags: regex

I try to build a regular expression to find all active console.log().
I don't want to find those which are unactive (after `//`).

In my sample, I want to match number 1, 4, 5, 6 and 9.

```
   console.log('1');
//       console.log('2');
// console.log("3");
console.log("4");
          console.log('5');
    console.log('6');
         //     console.log('7');
 //console.log('8');
      console.log("9");
```

I create a logic as :
`^(?!\s*\/\/)console\.log\(`

But it match only if console.log is at the very beginning of a line, despite I specify to match any whitespaces as many times as possible with `\s*`.

https://regex101.com/r/f4wYnG/1

What is not correct with my regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
^\s*console\.log\(
```

Works only if the line with "console.log", does not contain anything other than white spaces!

Or with keep using the "negative-lookahead"

```
^(?!.*\/\/).*console\.log\(
```

Both will find the lines you mentioned. The below is more accurate I think.

Answer (score 1):

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ grep -v '//' file
   console.log('1');
console.log("4");
          console.log('5');
    console.log('6');
      console.log("9");
```

Then, to match numbers:

```
$ grep -v '//' file | grep -oE '[0-9]+'
1
4
5
6
9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[/]+|^\s+[/]+/g
```

This is regex code that find '//'.

```
^\s*\w+
```

Above is regex code that find string starts with space or character.
It would be help to you.